# Dividing values of dictionaries by values of another dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, division

I have a dictionary, dict1, in the following format:

```
{0: 301, 1: 410, 2: 289}
```

I have another dictionary, dict2:

```
{0: 5307, 2: 4925}
```

I would like to divide the value of dict2 by the value of dict1, based on the keys. For example 5307 would be divided by 301 since their keys are both 0. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def divide(dividends, divisors):
    ret = dict()
    for key, dividend in dividends.items():
        ret[key] = dividend/divisors.get(key, 1)
    return ret
```

Comment: dividends.items() in Python 3 I guess

Comment: also should be  if key in divisors:

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> d1 = {0: 301, 1: 410, 2: 289}
>>> d2 = {0: 5307, 2: 4925}
>>> {k: d2[k] / float(d1[k]) for k in d1 if k in d2}
{0: 17.631229235880397, 2: 17.041522491349482}
```

If your Python (eg 2.6) is too old for dict comprehensions, you can use

```
>>> dict((k, d2[k] / float(d1[k])) for k in d1 if k in d2)
{0: 17.631229235880397, 2: 17.041522491349482}
```

If your Python is even older than 2.6

```
>>> dict([(k, d2[k] / float(d1[k])) for k in d1 if k in d2])
{0: 17.631229235880397, 2: 17.041522491349482}
```

In Python3, you don't need the `float` call

```
>>> {k: d2[k] / d1[k] for k in d1 if k in d2}
{0: 17.631229235880397, 2: 17.041522491349482}
```

Comment: any suggestions why I am receiving the following error?                     {k: d2[k] / float(d1[k]) for k in d1 if k in d2}
                           ^SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @user3547676, Your Python is very old. Is there a reason you're not using a newer one? Tell me which version you are using and I can update my answer.

Comment: I am currently using Python 2.7

Comment: @user3547676, I ran that exact code under 2.7 and pasted it here

Answer (score 0):

Loop over every item the length of the smallest dict. Then add the values to another dict, `values`.

```
>>> dict1 = {0: 301, 1: 410, 2: 289}
>>> 
>>> dict2 = {0: 5307, 1: 4925}
>>> 
>>> length = {len(dict1): 'dict1', len(dict2): 'dict2'}
>>> small = min(length)
>>> values = {}
>>> 
>>> for k in range(small):
...     values[k] = dict1[k]*dict2[k]
... 
>>> print values
{0: 1597407, 1: 2019250}
>>>
```